# How can I convert json request to php

Tags: php, json

I want to POST the following JSON HTTP API request in PHP

```
    curl -d '{"text":"Hello, #param#.","port":[2],"param":
    [{"number":"123456","text_param ":["John"],"user_id":1}]}’-u 
    myusername:mypassword –H "Content-Type: application/json"  
    http://accbd.com/api/send_req
```

Comment: to send http requests from PHP you need to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: How can I use -u 
    myusername:mypassword

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://accbd.com/api/send_req');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"text":"Hello, #param#.","port":[2],"param":[{"number":"123456","text_param ":["John"],"user_id":1}]}');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $data;exit;
```

Comment: got error  Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 400 Page not found Server: Web Server/2.1.0 Date: Sat Dec 23 10:07:17 2017 Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json

Comment: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.11.1:5851/api/send_sms');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ali:reza345934");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"text":"Hello, #param#.","port":[2,3],"param":[{"number":"01784787670","text_param ":["John"],"user_id":1},{"number":"01784787670", "text_param":["Sam"],"user_id":2}]}');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

Comment: Please use correct URL for CURLOPT_URL option. http://192.168.11.1:5851/api/send_sms seems not working.

Comment: If I add port then I got this error but if I not add port then got blank page. Noting happened